# Why is a recently declared file pointer returning (-1) despite the fact that the file stores data in it?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I am trying to write the data entered by user in one file, then reading the data from that file and encrypting it. However when I am declaring the file pointer for the second module its already returning (-1) without being used earlier.

```
//Entering Message to file
void enter_text(FILE *fp2)
{
        char ch;
        while ((ch = getchar())!=EOF)
        {
                putc(ch,fp2);
        }
}
int Encoding(char *argv_2,char *argv_3,char *argv_4)
{
        FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3, *fp_temp;
        int n, e;

        //opening the text file
        fp2 = fopen(argv_3, "w+");

        //Entering the text to file
        printf("Enter your secret text and Press CTRL + Z To Stop : \t");
        enter_text(fp2);//

        printf("Enter the value of n: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Enter the value of e: ");
        scanf("%d", &e);

        Encrypt(argv_3, n, e);
}
```

As for the second part of the code:

```
int Encrypt(char *argv_3, int n, int e)
{
        FILE *inp, *out;

        // destroy contents of these files (from previous runs, if any)
        out = fopen("cipher.txt", "w+");
        fclose(out);
        inp = fopen(argv_3, "r");
        if (inp == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening Source File.\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        out = fopen("cipher.txt", "w+");

        if (out == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening Destination File.\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        //Both getc(inp) and ch are retuning (-1) even after fseek()
        //printf("%d",getc(inp));
        //fseek(inp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

        // encryption starts
        while (1) {
                char ch = getc(inp);

        if (ch == -1)
                break;
        int value = toascii(ch);
        printf("%d",value);

        Encryption(value, out);
    }

    fclose(inp);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you call `fclose(fp2)`

Comment: Reading text typed by the user with `while ((ch = getchar())!=EOF)` will only work if the user generates a manual `EOF` by pressing **Ctrl + d** (Linux) or **Ctrl + z** (windows). Otherwise, `getchar()` will simply block waiting on more text after the **Enter** key is pressed at the end of the user-input. (you can read a redirected file that way).  In `Encrypt`, the value for `EOF` is generally `-1`, so you have an issue there. Impossible to identify with certainty without [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually this is a code for image steganography. So i am trying to encrypt the data first then encode it, that's why I haven't closed it before the call as I will need the fp2 while encoding.

Comment: Data written to a file is stored in a buffer until either A) the buffer fills up, or B) `fflush` is called, or C) `fclose` is called. So the data you wrote to the file in `Encoding` is not available for use in `Encrypt` unless one of those three things happens.

Comment: Well I have already tried ```while((getc(inp))!=EOF);``` and ```fflush(stdin);``` in place of fseek() @user3386109

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is illegal (according to the C specification), and I'm not talking about `stdin`. You need to `fflush(fp2)` before calling `Encrypt`. Otherwise, there isn't any data in the file when you call `inp = fopen(argv_3, "r")`

Comment: Thank you so very much, now its working fine. And sorry if the poorly formed question was inconvenient, it was my first question on stack overflow. Thanks again. @user3386109

Comment: OT: regarding: `char ch;
        while ((ch = getchar())!=EOF)`  The function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`